# How to calculate an optical axis line for planetary orbits around the sun to earth in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating an inner solar sytem model from the percpective of Earth for creating astology birthcharts references. I am able to draw an optical axis line for the Earth - Sun axis, and the Earth - Moon axis but I can not for the life of me figure the trigonometry for the remaining inner planets.
Here is a working pen.
https://codepen.io/pjdroopypants/pen/wvEKeOm

```
window.onload = function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height,
    time = 1;

function circle(radius,color,x,y){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}


function line(color,ax,ay,bx,by){

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ax*2,ay);
    ctx.lineTo(bx+0.5,by+0.5);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

}

var sunDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359) + 1; //temporary, will use function from live planetary data
var merDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359) + 1; //temporary, will use function from live planetary data 
var venDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359) + 1; //temporary, will use function from live planetary data 
var marDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359) + 1; //temporary, will use function from live planetary data 
var mooDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359) + 1; //temporary, will use function from live planetary data 
var interval = 570.0930061551268;

function animate(){

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1100, 1100);
    ctx.translate(cw/2,ch/2);

    //Earth 
    ctx.rotate(-(time / interval)+ Math.PI);
    circle(15,"blue",0,0);
    ctx.translate(480,0);
    line("blue",-240,0,0,0);
    ctx.translate(-480,0);
    ctx.rotate((time / interval)+ Math.PI);

        //Moon
        var moontime = (time / (interval / 13.36996336996337)+mooDegree);
        ctx.rotate(-moontime);
        ctx.translate(23,0);
        circle(3,"black",0,0);
        ctx.translate(457,0);
        line("#6a6a6a",-230,0,0,0);
        ctx.translate(-480,0);
        ctx.rotate(moontime);

    //Sun
    var suntime = time / interval;
    ctx.rotate(-suntime);
    ctx.translate(120,0);
    circle(15,"yellow",0,0);
    ctx.translate(360,0);
    line("yellow",-182,0,0,0);
    ctx.translate(-360,0);
    ctx.rotate(suntime);

    //Mercury
    var mertime = (time / (interval / 4.150568181818182))+merDegree;
    ctx.rotate(-(time / (interval / 4.150568181818182))+merDegree-suntime);
    ctx.translate(40,0);
    circle(15,"#898989",0,0);

    ctx.translate(-40,0);
    ctx.rotate((time / (interval / 4.150568181818182))+merDegree+suntime);

    //Venus
    ctx.rotate(-(time / (interval / 1.625500667556742))+venDegree-suntime);
    ctx.translate(80,0);
    circle(15,"#b9955b",0,0);
    ctx.translate(-80,0);
    ctx.rotate((time / (interval / 1.625500667556742))+venDegree);

    //Mars
    ctx.rotate(-(time / (interval / 0.5316593886462882))+marDegree);
    ctx.translate(160,0);
    circle(15,"#9f5e13",0,0);
    ctx.translate(-160,0);
    ctx.rotate((time / (interval / 0.5316593886462882))+marDegree);

    ctx.restore();
    time++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

I attempted to reverse rotate each animation iteration by subtracting the suns rotating angle but that just makes the axis line horizontal and not back to center.

Comment: What do you mean by "optical axis line"? Google talks about them in reference to lenses, which I dont see any mention of here. Wouldn't one just assign an arbitrary orientation to an X,Y,Z coordinate system that the planets and sun exist within, before animating that and showing the appearance from some arbitrary point and orientation?

Comment: The line function I have in the code. It is the optical axis lines I am referring to, the code pen I provided shows lines coming from the sun, earth, and moon opposite side of the earth illustrating the straight line through each planets center for the use of a dial. My appologies for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Encapsulate using objects

Your code is a mess

You need to encapsulate the various parts so you can work with them individually.

The example below defines planets using a factory pattern to create planets as objects.

Each planet gets orbital ang, rate, and distance from the planet they orbit. Eg Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars all orbit the Sun, and the Moon orbits the Earth.

Planets are created in orbital order. IE can not create planet before you create the planet it orbits.

On each animation frame each planet's position is calculated relative to the planet it orbits in the same order as they were created.

Before rendering the planet we want to center the view on a selected planet (in this case the Earth). The centered planets position is used to create a global matrix that will move all planets to the correct position.

Then when drawing each planet we multiply the global matrix by the planet's matrix `ctx.setTransform(...globalMat); ctx.transform(this.cos, this.sin, -this.sin, this.cos, this.x, this.y);` and draw the result

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const centerOnPlanetName = "Earth";  // Planet name to center view on
const globalMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];  // holds position of planet to track
const solSystem = {};                // holds planets by name
const planets = [];                  // holds planets in order of created
const planetCommon = {               // common properties of planets
     x: 0, y: 0, cos: 1, sin: 0,
     update(time) {
         this.ang = this.startAng + this.orbitalSpeed * time;
         this.cos = Math.cos(this.ang);
         this.sin = Math.sin(this.ang);
         if (this.orbits) {          // Check if orbiting something
             this.x = this.orbits.x + this.cos * this.dist;
             this.y = this.orbits.y + this.sin * this.dist;
         } 
     },
     draw(ctx, globalMat) {
         ctx.setTransform(...globalMat);
         ctx.transform(this.cos, this.sin, -this.sin, this.cos, this.x, this.y);
         ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, TAU);
         ctx.fill();
         if (this.dirTo !== undefined) {
             ctx.beginPath();
             const ax = Math.cos(this.dirTo);
             const ay = Math.sin(this.dirTo);
             ctx.lineTo(ax * this.radius * 1.5, ay * this.radius * 1.5);
             ctx.lineTo(ax * this.distTo, ay * this.distTo);
             ctx.stroke();         
         }
     },
     directionTo(planet) {
         if (planet !== this) {
              this.dirTo = Math.atan2(planet.y - this.y, planet.x - this.x) - this.ang;
              this.distTo = Math.hypot(planet.y - this.y, planet.x - this.x);
         } else {
              this.dirTo = undefined;
         }
     }
};
const planet = (name, orbitsName, dist, orbitalSpeed, startAng, radius, color) => {
    planets.push(solSystem[name] = {
        orbits: solSystem[orbitsName], // Set planet new planet orbits
        dist,                          // dist from orbiting body
        orbitalSpeed,                  // in radians per time unit
        startAng,                      // starting angle in radians
        radius,
        color,
        ...planetCommon,
     });
};
planet("Sun", undefined,     0, 0.8, - Math.PI, 20, "yellow");
planet("Mercury", "Sun",    45,   2,         0,  6, "#888");
planet("Venus",   "Sun",    70, 1.2,         0, 15, "#CC8");
planet("Earth",   "Sun",   120, 0.8,         0, 16, "#39B");
planet("Mars",    "Sun",   175, 0.4,         0, 10, "#B43");
planet("Moon",    "Earth",  30,   5,         0,  3, "#444");

function centerOn(cx, cy, planet) {
    globalMatrix[4] = cx - planet.x;
    globalMatrix[5] = cy - planet.y;
}

function mainLoop(time) {
    time /= 1000;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    planets.forEach(planet => planet.update(time));
    planets.forEach(planet => planet.directionTo(solSystem[centerOnPlanetName]));
    centerOn(ctx.canvas.width * 0.5, ctx.canvas.height * 0.5, solSystem[centerOnPlanetName]);
    planets.forEach(planet => planet.draw(ctx, globalMatrix));
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you that does help me with as far as maintaining this code.The thing I believe I am failing to convey is the line if sight from each of the orbiting planets must be pointed in towards the very central planet, in this case the earth.

Comment: @ChadMcCammon That is easy to do, but busy at the moment, will do in the next few days when i get a chance. You can use `Math.aTan2(solSystem.Mars.y - solSystem.Earth.y, solSystem.Mars.x - solSystem.Earth.x)` to get the direction in radians eg Mars to Earth. And some mods to the draw function to draw the line along that direction.

Comment: @ChadMcCammon I have added updates to demo code

Comment: Works brilliantly sir thank you for spending the time, You've taught me a lot of things within this answer.